# How to create a auto complete validation for a textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery

How is possible to create a auto complete validation for a textbox with Jquery? I mean, if the textbox accept only numbers (Using the numeric.js) but should be a % field and the user forget to write the '%'. How is possible to generate a auto complete that fill up the rest of the text with the '%' simbol?
THX!

Comment: Why make the user enter `%`? Put that in the HTML outside the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.  I'm also removing the "%" whenever the user edits the field and removing the value if the user enters an invalid character.

```js
$(".percentage").blur(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  value = value.replace('%', '');
  if (isNaN(value))
    value = '';
  else
    value = value + '%';
  $(this).val(value);
});

$(".percentage").focus(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace('%', ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="percentage" />
```

Comment: @gonzalezzoe no problem, glad to help.